Calculate total population within a boundary GDB and population density map GeoTiff
I have a High Resolution Population Density Map GeoTiff which I can load through rioxarray, and a list of boundaries in GDB format which I can load through GeoPandas.
I would like to calculate the total population within one of the boundaries contained in the GDB. While it seems to work, I am getting a much larger value than expected.
Loading other similar density maps and different set of boundaries also severely overestimate the expected population; the problem is likely with my code.
Any help would be immensely appreciated.
The High Resolution Population Density GeoTiff can be downloaded here
The GDB file containing the boundaries are found here
import geopandas as gpd
import rioxarray as rxr

# Load boundary file
df = gpd.read_file("WDPA_WDOECM_May2024_Public_COG.gdb")

# Load Human population GeoTiff
xds = rxr.open_rasterio("cog_general_2020.tif", masked=True, from_disk=True)
xds["mask"] = 0

# Reproject to an area preserving CRS centered in Congo
df = df.to_crs("+proj=cea +lat_0=1.346245 +lon_0=17.150298 +units=km")
xds = xds.rio.reproject("+proj=cea +lat_0=1.346245 +lon_0=17.150298 +units=km")
# Reprojecting with df = df.to_crs(xds.rio.crs) instead gives the same result

# Filter out Lac Tele, one of the boundaries
lactele = df[(df['NAME'] == 'Lac Télé')]
xds_lactele = xds.rio.clip(lactele.geometry.values, df.crs, from_disk=True)

# Calculate the total population within the boundary
total_pop = xds_lactele.where(xds_lactele > 0).sum().compute()

# Expected 20k, finding 85k. Other boundaries are also being severely overestimated


Welcome to [so]! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses such as "Any help would be immensely appreciated: are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over Where to Start, and [mre] then edit your post.

Density sounds like the units should be something like number of peoples / area units? I cant find the metadata. If so, summing it will not give correct total population

@BERA Good point! I think the resolution is correct, since calling xds_lactele.rio.resolution() returns 0.03 (30 meters), which is correct according to Meta methodology.
Searching further in the web, I may need to multiply the summed value by the resolution squared, to get number of people, but that result is also entirely out of the expected range.
